# Rally Integration with Subversion both ways

Tags: svn, rally

I see from the link [Rally Integration with Subversion](http://www.rallydev.com/help/subversion-installation-user-guide) that Any update on `check-ins` will get updated to Rally. But is there a way to get this done in `reverse way`. What I want to ask is If i create a defect in `svn/track` then will it get automatically updated into `Rally` Or I update the defect in `svn/track` will i get notification in Rally.